# iteration of a dictionary in java

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have a big amount of data that I have saved in interfaces (55 to be exact). combined they contain almost 170000 strings in string arrays.

What I want to do is match the input element to the strings in given interface and return all the elements that match the pattern of the input element.

I have saved the elements in string arrays eg.

```
String[] array = {"element 1", "element 2".....};
```

for every input I have to iterate the string array whole in order to find all the matching elements in the list.

I am currently doing this:

```
for(int innerIterator = 0; innerIterator < dictionaryArrayLength; innerIterator++){
            if (dictionaryArray[innerIterator].matches(""+input[iterator]+"\\D*")) {
                matchedWordList.add(dictionaryArray[innerIterator]);
            }
        }
```

as the length of the array is in thousands so its taking a bit of time to answer.

I would like this code to perform better. I am currently thinking to change the data structure I have used for the dictionaries. But is there any better way to iterate through the list and find all the matching elements

Comment: For one thing, you could compile the `""+input[iterator]+"\\D*"` pattern outside that for loop.

Comment: You can also sort your `dictionaryArray`s, and then use binary search to find all of the strings starting with the given prefix.

Comment: Maybe [Rabin–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) can be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you could try with the new Stream api:

```
Pattern inputPatter = Pattern.compile(input[iterator] + "\\D*");
List<String> matchingWords = Arrays.stream(dictionaryArray).parallel()
        .filter(word -> inputPatter.matcher(word).matches()).collect(Collectors.toList());
matchedWordList.addAll(matchingWords);
```

With the first line (`Pattern inputPatter = Pattern.compile(input[iterator] + "\\D*");`) you avoid

1. The creation of the regex string at every cycle iteration
2. The creation of the relative Pattern object at every iteration (see the source code of `String.matches`)

With `Arrays.stream` you create a stream from an array.

With `.parallel` you parallelize the stream in order to distribute the following operations among multiple threads (with huge sets of data it can improve performances considerably).

With `.filter(word -> inputPatter.matcher(word).matches())` you select only the words matching your pattern.

With `.collect(Collectors.toList())` you collect your results in a list.